# Apache NiFi dynamic atributes for PutDatabaseRecord Processor

Tags: etl, apache-nifi

I have this flow in NiFi:

> GetFile -> ConvertExcelToCSVProcessor -> ReplaceText ->
>   PutDatabaseRecord.

It's working ok but I want to set "table name" property of

> PutDatabaseRecord

based on csv file name (and if it's posible to customize it). I can't find anything in docs or web.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to documentation, the parameter `table name` of the [PutDatabaseRecord](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.9.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.PutDatabaseRecord/) processor supports [nifi expression language](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/expression-language-guide.html).

So, if the attribute `filename` of your flow file contains value `MyTableName.csv` you could use expression with regular expression to convert file name to table name in PutDatabaseRecord processor like this:

```groovy
Table Name = ${filename:replaceAll('\\..*','')}
```